# how to uninstall component using helm in kuberetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am install promethus-operator using helm v3.2.1 like this:

```
./helm install stable/prometheus-operator --generate-name -n dabai-pro
```

now I want to move the component prometheus-operator from `dabai-pro` namespace to `monitoring` namespace and want to delete this installing, I read the docs and doing like this:

```
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm uninstall stable/prometheus-operator -n dabai-pro
Error: uninstall: Release name is invalid: stable/prometheus-operator
```

and like this :

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm uninstall prometheus-operator -n dabai-pro
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: prometheus-operator: release: not found
```

so what should I do to remove it?

```
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm list -n dabai-pro
NAME                    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART               APP VERSION
prometheus-1591246262   dabai-pro   1           2020-06-04 12:51:03.763613003 +0800 CST deployed    prometheus-11.3.0   2.18.1
redis-ha-1591192248     dabai-pro   1           2020-06-03 21:50:50.316917158 +0800 CST deployed    redis-ha-4.4.4      5.0.6
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm uninstall prometheus-1591246262
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: prometheus-1591246262: release: not found
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm uninstall prometheus-11.3.0
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: prometheus-11.3.0: release: not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below command to view the release name and namespacename

```
helm list
```

And uninstall the release by

```
helm uninstall releasename -n namespacename
```

In your case it will be

```
./helm uninstall prometheus-1591246262 -n dabai-pro
```

Comment: Still could not find the release name @Arghya Sadhu

Comment: `[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm uninstall prometheus-11.3.0 -n dabai-pro
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: prometheus-11.3.0: release: not found` stil not work, I do not know why?@Arghya Sadhu

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you run?

```
helm list --all-namespaces
```

It should list your helm deployment.  The --generate-name parameter generated a random name.  When you run the uninstall command, both the namespace and the generated name need to be supplied as specified in the earlier answer.

```
./helm uninstall prometheus-1591246262 -n dabai-pro
```